# How to kill mysql (Percona Xtradb Cluster) service in Linux?

Tags: centos, systemd, cluster, percona

I cannot fully kill a mysql service on CentOS 7. I tried to find all PIDs:

```
ps -ef | grep 'mysql'
```

and then kill them with `kill -9 ...`

but mysql recreates after some time.

Also I tried to kill it like this:

```
killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
```

The same effect. After several seconds mysql rejoins.

Why it happens?

EDITED:

```
# ps aux | grep mysql
root     15284  0.0  0.3 115384  1804 ?        Ss   12:10   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr  --wsrep-new-cluster 
mysql    15743  0.1 40.3 1353412 202276 ?      Sl   12:10   0:03 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --wsrep-provider=/usr/lib64/galera3/libgalera_smm.so --wsrep-new-cluster --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --wsrep_start_position=43de3d74-bca8-11e6-a178-57b39b925285:9                                                                                                                         
root     16303  0.0  0.1 112648   976 pts/0    R+   12:56   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

I am using a mysql fork (Percona Xtradb Cluster) and it can't be stopped if the node is partitioned from the cluster. It can be stopped only if I disable a mysql service and reboot a node. But it is much better for me to kill the process without node rebooting. So

```
systemctl stop mysql
```

Doesn't work. It tries to stop it but without success.

I have installed it from Percona repository via yum:

```
yum install Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-57
```

Situation is the next:
There was 3 nodes and they crashed. After some time only 2 nodes could start. But they are waiting for the 3rd node. They have state: activating. If I try to stop mysql service then it change its state to: deactivating. But it can't be stopped. So, I try to kill mysql service and provision a new cluster from 2 nodes. But I can't stop mysql without reboot (reboot isn't a solution for me).

Comment: can you post the output of  `ps aux | grep  mysql` ?

Comment: I have edited a question. Added output

Comment: You may have a service running that is restarting mariadb. For example on webservers with cPanel installed, there is a chksrvd process that monitors other services and restarts them. A bit more background information on your server and its function would be helpful for us

Comment: I have edited my question. I am using Percona Xtradb Cluster without cPanel. I have installed only Percona Xtradb Cluster with this command: sudo yum install Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found why it reboots.

In the service file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service` there was enabled restart:

```
Restart=always
```

I commented it:

```
#Restart=always
```

After machine reboot I can kill a mysql process as follows:

```
killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you  check "/etc/inittab" entry for MySQL if it is starting with respawn .
If it is , then you can comment out the line in "/etc/inittab"
Try killing mysql with
kill -HUP PID of MYSQL

Comment: I haven't anything except comments in "/etc/inittab". 'kill -HUP PID' also doesn't work (the same result then I try to stop mysql)..